# JPA standalone mode - changing managed entity fields outside EntityTransaction works - why?

Tags: java, jpa

I am experimenting with **JPA** in standalone mode (backed by Hibernate).
I've noticed that the following code succeeds in changing the database value to "garbled":

```
A a = em.find(A.class, 1);
a.setA1("garbled");
entityTransaction.begin();   // line 3
entityTransaction.commit();  // line 4
em.close();
```

There is no other transaction **begin()** before **line 3**.
The language used in the [API spec for EntityTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html) would seem to indicate otherwise or perhaps something is a bit counter-intuitive in the model of demarcating a **JPA** entity transaction with **begin()** and **commit()**? Note that lines **3** and **4** are necessary as commenting them out does not change the database value.

Comment: I'd agree the behaviour is counter intuitive (and the answer you're given is totally correct), and that's why some JPA implementations like DataNucleus JPA provide "atomic" non-transactional operations, whereby your "a.setA1()" would go to the datastore immediately (like "auto-commit" in JDBC) rather than having to start a new transaction to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` in your example is a managed entity associated with `em` instance, can be modified outside a transaction boundary and will be persisted as part of committing a transaction from the same entity manager instance. The transaction boundaries only define what goes into the database when the transaction is committed and what changes made to the DB get reverted when the transaction fails. Assuming that you failed the transaction in your example, `a` would still have the changes made, it is only that the database will not have these changes and so are not visible to others.

If you were expecting that managed entities should not be modifiable outside the transaction boundaries, or any changes to them outside the transaction boundaries shouldn't get persisted, then that is not true. The life cycle of a managed entity is tied with its entity manager.

Comment: So, what goes to the DB is whatever's inside the transaction boundaries PLUS any changes made to managed entities ?

Comment: Yes, the commit on a transaction from a given entity manager flushes all the modified managed entities of that entity manager, to the database.